# perl TemplateToolkit - Can't locate object method "new" via package

Tags: perl, templates, cgi, ubuntu-9.10

I have inherited a web project that is perl based and I'm attempting to set up a local testing server so changes can be made internally to the project.

The server architecture
Ubuntu 9.10
php 5.2.10
mysql 5.1.37
perl 5.10.0-24ubuntu4

All the dependent modules and packages are installed such as DateTime.pm, TemplateToolkit.pm but running the application throws the following error message:

***Can't locate object method "new" via package "Template" (perhaps you forgot to load "Template"?) at ../lib//KPS/TemplateToolkit.pm line 51***

The code block that this refers to is:

```
sub new {
    return Template->new(
        INCLUDE_PATH => $KPS::Config::templatepath,
        ABSOLUTE     => 1,
        DEBUG        => 1,
    );
}
```

If anybody is able to shed any light on this or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Simnom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to load Template Toolkit first, with:

```
use Template;
```

To make sure that Template::Toolkit is properly installed on this system, from a console you could run:

```
perl -MTemplate -e0
```

If it returns without an error, it means Template.pm wsa loaded succesfully; if not, it will give you an error of "Can't locate Template.pm in @INC...".

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for the response.  I've added use Template; to the head of the script concerned before posting without any luck.

The head of the script is as follows:

use strict;
use warnings;

package KPS::TemplateToolkit;

use Template;
use KPS::Config;
use KPS::Globals;

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, from a console, run something like:
perl -MTemplate -e0
- does it give you any error?

Comment: By the way, I believe that TT's new() method expects a hashref of params, so your invocation should look like Template->new({ ... }) - that should not cause the error you're seeing, though.

Comment: Thanks a million, this gives me some more ammo to hunt with.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An additional thing to check because the accepted answer test could be successful even if you are not setup correctly; make sure that the package declaration in the module has the correct path.  The scenario is as follows:

You do

```
use a::b;
...
a::b->new();
```

and then in b.pm you do

```
package b;
```

You may be banging your head for a while until you realize that you need to do

```
package a::b;
```